# java.net.ConnectException Exception while trying to insert the data into Fauxton couchDB

Tags: java

Here, I have created the database in the **fauxton couchDB**.

When I try to insert the data into the database, I get `java.net.ConnectException`.

when the `button` is clicked, I get `Failed 500 server error the call failed on the server see server log for details`.

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public FieldVerifier createDB(FieldVerifier fieldVerifier) {
        final String FIRSTNAME ="FirstName";

        final String LASTNAME ="LastName";

        final String CLASS="course";
        final String ADDRESS="address"; 
        /*Creating a session with couch db running in 5984 port*/
        Session studentDbSession = new Session("192.168.1.48",5984);

        /*Selecting the 'student' database from list of couch database*/
        Database couchDb = studentDbSession.getDatabase("shalinicouchdb");

        Document newdoc = new Document();

        HashMap<String , String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

        System.out.println(fieldVerifier.getFirstname()+" "+fieldVerifier.getLastname()+" "+fieldVerifier.getCourse()+
                  " "+fieldVerifier.getAddress());

        hashMap.put(FIRSTNAME,fieldVerifier.getFirstname());
        hashMap.put(LASTNAME,fieldVerifier.getLastname());
        hashMap.put(CLASS, fieldVerifier.getCourse());
        hashMap.put(ADDRESS, fieldVerifier.getAddress());

        newdoc.putAll(hashMap);

        /*Saving the new document in the 'student' database */
        couchDb.saveDocument(newdoc);  

        return fieldVerifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find any `connect` does `getDatabase` also creates a connection? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817110/how-to-connect-couchdb-with-java this may help you.